# Solr Last index time

Tags: solr

How do I get solr last index time  ?. Is there a query to get that or do I have any timestamps that I can go with or do I have to keep a note of the last indextime manually if I am running in the solrnet?.

Answer (score 3):

I always put `<field name="updated" type="date" default="NOW"/>` into my indexes. I will have to look into the LukeRequestHandler.

Comment: Some details on where exactly in the `SolrConfig.xml` this `<field name="updated" type="date" default="NOW"/>` should be placed, would be nice. I've been searching the web like a loony for hours finding only messy pages saying irrelevant things...

Comment: OK. I think I've got this (by searching the file structure)! It must be in the `schema.xml` of the collection!

Answer (score 2):

The `LukeRequestHandler` would give you the time in the `lastModified` field.

Have a look [here](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/LukeRequestHandler) for more details.